# how can I find out if I'm inside a git submodule?

Tags: git, shell, git-submodules

tldr; How can I find out that my current working directory is inside of a submodule directory?

Work processes differ if working inside or outside submodules. And time and again I get confused because I am not aware that i'm inside a submodule.

Optimally `__git_ps1` would show me that I'm inside a submodule, but apparently it has no provisions to do so.

I'd like to patch `__git_ps1` to show me the fact that I'm inside a submodule, but I can't find an elegant way to query git for that fact.

Ideally I'd like to have a shell function like this:

```
function current_working_directory_is_in_a_submodule() {
  if some_magic; then
     echo "( $submodule_name )"
  else
     false
  fi
}
```

What's `some_magic`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Submodule-ness is just a question of how a repo's being used, whether the current checkout is what some other checkout thinks should be there.

You can see whether the work tree is inside another work tree that thinks there should be a checkout here:

```
top=`git rev-parse --show-toplevel 2>&-` || exit
if up=`git -C "$top/.." rev-parse --show-toplevel 2>&-` 
then    echo work tree is at ${top#$up/} in another work tree
        at=`git -C "$up" rev-parse :${top#$up/}` && echo ... which thinks $(git cat-file -t $at) $at should be checked out there
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

[`git rev-parse --show-superproject-working-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt---show-superproject-working-tree)

Outputs nothing if the current repository is not used as a submodule by any project.

Comment: Note: this was new in Git 2.13, and there was a minor bug fix in 2.19.2 (it glitched if the superproject had a submodule merge conflict). Info found by running `git log -S show-superproject-working-tree` in the Git repository for Git, and then checking containing tags for the revisions that were listed.

Answer (score 2):

Potentially you can look at the `.git` directory. If it's *not* actually a directory, you can be pretty sure you're in a submodule.  At least with recent versions of git, the `.git` entry is actually a file that looks something like:

```
gitdir: ../../../.git/modules/path/to/submodule
```

Depending on how the submodule was added, it may still have a `.git` directory. There is a `git submodule absorbgitdirs` command that can be run in the parent repository that will fix this; from the `git submodule` man page:

> If a git directory of a submodule is inside the submodule, move the git directory of the submodule into its superprojects $GIT_DIR/modules path and then connect the git directory and its working directory by setting the core.worktree and adding a .git file pointing to the git directory embedded in the superprojects git directory.
>
> A repository that was cloned independently and later added as a submodule or old setups have the submodules git directory inside the submodule instead of embedded into the superprojects git directory.
>
> This command is recursive by default.

...but this is still problematic because while the test is easy when you're in the root of the submodule, it's more difficult when you're in a deeply nested directory (because then you would have to iteratively search parent directories until you find a `.git` directory or you reach `/`).

---

The man page entry I quoted above points us at a second, better option:

In a submodule, the `core.worktree` value is set (to a relative path from the root of the submodule back to itself). This means you can (a) check if the `core.worktree` setting has a value to determine whether or not you're in a submodule, and (b) you can use the value of `core.worktree` to determine the submodule name.  That gets us something like:

```
function current_working_directory_is_in_a_submodule() {
  submodule=$(git config core.worktree)
  if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
     echo "( ${submodule##*/} )"
  else
     false
  fi
}
```

I don't know if there are other situations in which `core.worktree` will be set automatically, but this seems to work in my limited testing.